# How do I fill context menu to my button right click?

Tags: c#

I create a new button on code editor and design a contextmenu and then I need to show my contextmenu when new button right click, but it does not read.

```
  Button btn = new Button();
  btn.Width = 125;
  btn.Height = 100;
  btn.ContextMenu = Menu_navigations;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What framework is this? do you ever add the button to something?

Comment: I see a couple of things wrong. 1- The tags could be improved. I guess this is Winforms or WPF, maybe winforms? 2- There is not much code, you reference a menu named `Menu_navigations` but there is no code about it. Check the [mcve]

Comment: There's an example [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-create-context-menu-in-windows-forms-application-usin/)